# Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I try to backup a server using Paramiko and SSH to call a `tar` command. When there is a limited number of files, all works well but when it's a big folder, the script wait endlessly. The following test shows me that the problem comes from the size of the stdout.

Is there a way to correct that and execute this kind of command?

Case big output:

```
query = 'cd /;ls -lshAR -h'
chan.exec_command(query)
while not chan.recv_exit_status():
    if chan.recv_ready():
        data = chan.recv(1024)
        while data:
            print data
            data = chan.recv(1024)

    if chan.recv_stderr_ready():
        error_buff = chan.recv_stderr(1024)
        while error_buff:
            print error_buff
            error_buff = chan.recv_stderr(1024)
    exist_status = chan.recv_exit_status()
    if 0 == exist_status:
        break
```

Result is (not ok - block - die ??)

```
2015-07-25 12:57:07,402 --> Query sent
```

Case small output:

```
query = 'cd /;ls -lshA -h'
chan.exec_command(query)
while not chan.recv_exit_status():
    if chan.recv_ready():
        data = chan.recv(1024)
        while data:
            print data
            data = chan.recv(1024)

    if chan.recv_stderr_ready():
        error_buff = chan.recv_stderr(1024)
        while error_buff:
            print error_buff
            error_buff = chan.recv_stderr(1024)
    exist_status = chan.recv_exit_status()
    if 0 == exist_status:
        break
```

Result is (all is ok)

```
2015-07-25 12:55:08,205 --> Query sent
total 172K
4.0K drwxr-x---   2 root psaadm 4.0K Dec 27  2013 archives
   0 -rw-r--r--   1 root root      0 Jul  9 23:49 .autofsck
   0 -rw-r--r--   1 root root      0 Dec 27  2013 .autorelabel
4.0K dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root   4.0K Dec 23  2014 bin
2015-07-25 12:55:08,307 --> Query executed (0.10)
```

Put on GitHub:
https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/563

Comment: Put on GitHub => https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/563

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `ls -R` prints lots of error output (what is likely if the current user is not `root` => does not have access to all folders), your code [deadlocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) eventually.

It's because, the output buffer of the error stream eventually fills, so the `ls` stops working, waiting for you to read the stream (empty the buffer).

While you wait for the regular output stream to finish, what it never does, as the `ls` waits for you to read the error stream, what you never do.

You have to read both streams in parallel (see [Run multiple commands in different SSH servers in parallel using Python Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66191219/850848)).

Or even easier, use the [`Channel.set_combine_stderr`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.set_combine_stderr) to merge both streams into one.

Answer (score 0):

read data before check exit status

[channel.recv_exit_status() hanging](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/448)