# Paramiko stdout readline() command hangs

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, ftp, paramiko

I am using the the python paramiko library to SSH into a FTP server. I am able to use the command line to access the server and retrieve a list of files using the sftp command, however paramiko seems to be doing something that prevents me from retrieving output. Here is my python code:

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()

client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client.connect('###########',
        port=##,
        username='####',
        password='####',
        key_filename='#####')

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
```

this all works just fine. However the next line

```
stdout.readline()
```

just sits there and hangs. Notice that per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266753/paramiko-python-module-hangs-at-stdout-read) I am not even trying to retrieve the full output, just the first line.

I also tried

```
stdin.close()
print(stdout.readlines())
```

which returns an empty string. This suggests that maybe the server is waiting for input, but when I use the command line I am able to just send the ls command and get the output so what command could it be waiting for?

Versions:

- python 3.7.4
- paramiko 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Your readline might be executing before there is a return from the remote host try:

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()

client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

client.connect('###########',
        port=##,
        username='####',
        password='####',
        key_filename='#####')

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')        
stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()
print(stdout.readline())
```

The recv_exit_status() will wait until there is a return from exec_command() on your remote host.

Comment: I have tried waiting up to 30s before executing the readline command. There are only a handful of files on the server (which is on aws) and I have a decent internet connection. I can't see that being the issue.

Comment: It sounds like you might be hanging on the client.connect() and not actually setting up the tunnel for exec_command(). Add a try catch around the connect and add an auth timeout arg `try:
client.connect('###########',
        port=##,
        username='####',
        password='####',
        key_filename='#####',
        timeout=5.0)

except (Exception) as e:
            return print('Error connecting to ssftp: {}'.format(e))
            sys.exit(0)`