# Unzip hangs when excecuting it with Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

folks,

I faced an issue unzipping files via SSH using Python Paramiko library.I download a .zip file using wget and try to unzip it with this command:

```
client = SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname=host,port=port, username=user, password=psw)
stdin,stdout,stderr = client.exec_command('unzip /path/to/file.zip', get_pty=True)

for line in iter(stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line, end="")
```

it finds a file tries to unzip it and hangs..

```
Archive:  /path/to/file.zip
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Why `get_pty=True`? What does your code do after `exec_command`? How do you detect that it hangs?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl to get a pseudo-terminal so I could see what is happening there. It does nothing after it executes this command. I claim that it hangs because it outputs```Archive:  /path/to/file.zip ``` and then nothing happens program is still running but that all..

Comment: edited my post to make things more clear for you guys :)

Comment: How do you know what it's outputting? Do you have some code that reads from stdout or stderr? Please [edit] your question to include that code.

Comment: I do not see how `get_pty=True` alone gets you any output. You must be reading it first. Where's your code for that? + Have you seen this? [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl sorry my bad, edited my question

Comment: So did you follow the link I've posted in my previous comment?

Comment: Hi, yea, now it works :) thank you @MartinPrikryl !