# readline hangs on paramiko.Channel when reading "watch" command output

Tags: python, shell, paramiko

I am testing this code to read the output of `watch` command. I suspect it has to do with how `watch` works, but I can't figure out what's wrong or how to work around it:

```
import paramiko

host = "micro"
# timeout = 2  # Succeeds
timeout = 3  # Hangs!
command = 'ls / && watch -n2 \'touch "f$(date).txt"\''

ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(host, password='', look_for_keys=False)

transport = ssh_client.get_transport()
channel = transport.open_session()
channel.get_pty()
channel.settimeout(timeout)
channel.set_combine_stderr(True)
stdout = channel.makefile()
channel.exec_command(command)

for line in stdout:  # Hangs here
    print(line.strip())
```

There are several similar issues, some of them quite old ([1](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/109), [2](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/515), and probably others)

This does not happen with other commands that don't use `watch` either.

**Does someone know what's special about this particular command and / or how to reliably set a timeout for the read operation?**

(Tested on Python 3.4.2 and paramiko 1.15.1)

*Edit 1*: I incorporated `channel.set_combine_stderr(True)` [as suggested in this answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31650750/554319), but still didn't do the trick. However, `watch` does produce a lot of output, so perhaps the problem is exactly that. In fact, using this command removed the hanging:

```
command = 'ls / && watch -n2 \'touch "f$(date).txt"\' > /dev/null'
```

So, probably this question is almost a duplicate of [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/554319), but makes me wonder if **there's really no way to use `.readline()` (called through `__next__` in this case)** and one has to resort to read with a fixed buffer size and assemble the lines manually.

Comment: See [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/554319).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably hangs because `watch` does not produce newlines. If one replaces

```
for line in stdout:
    print(line.strip())
```

with a busy loop with

```
stdout.readline(some_fixed_size)
```

it can be seen that the bytes never contain a newline character. Therefore, this is a very special case and is not related to other hangs reported in other issues and SO questions.