# paramiko - invoke script.py on remote server and continue

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Im using paramiko to execute python script on remote machine.
I want paramiko to execute the script on the remote machine and continue without closing the script.

this my code now:

```
command = "python3 script.py"

client = paramiko.SSHClient() 
client.load_system_host_keys()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
client.connect(ip,port,user,password)

stdin, stdout, stderr = self.client.exec_command(command)

while(True):
     "do something"
```

So right now the python script is starting and finishing really fast (altought it suppose to run for hour) and then "do something" happend.
I want the script.py to finish on the remoth machine while "do something" happend.
"Invoke the script and forget about it"

Answer (score 1):

That's what your code does. But if the command prints (lots of) output, once the output buffers fill, [the script will hang and never finish](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).

If you are not interested in the output, an easy solution is to discard the it:

```
command = "python3 script.py > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

Comment: It doesnt give me exactly what i wanted. but i added threading and it give me solution. so thank you