# ssh_channel_request_exec is not working without ssh_channel_read

Tags: c, ssh

I am using `ssh_channel_request_exec` to execute a command `mkdir -p ~/.temp` on a remote node. When `ssh_channel_request_exec` is used along with `ssh_channel_read`, the creation of directory is working fine. On the other hand, when `ssh_channel_read` is not used, the directory creation is failing.

In this case, `ssh_channel_request_exec` is not going to write anything to the channel. So, what is the relevance of `ssh_channel_read` here?

```
int exec_result = ssh_channel_request_exec(channel, "mkdir -p ~/.temp");
if (exec_result != SSH_OK)
{
    ssh_channel_close(channel);
    ssh_channel_free(channel);
    ssh_disconnect(session);
    ssh_free(session);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the command to complete, before closing the channel.

The side effect of the `ssh_channel_read` is that it delays closing the channel, until after your command completes. Possibly not always – so you might just have been lucky so far that it delayed closing long enough – longer running commands than `mkdir` might still fail.

If you do not want to read the output, you should be able to use [`ssh_channel_get_exit_status`](https://api.libssh.org/master/group__libssh__channel.html#ga9eea019dd0bbaa8a817fff2c762d1a2d) to determine if the command completed.

I do not know sshlib API enough, but in general, you need to read the output anyway. Because if you do not, and the command produces enough output to fill the output buffer, the command will hang. See these questions about different SSH APIs:

- [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848)
- [How to read JSch command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6902386/850848)

---

*Side note: For file system operations, you should better use a standard SSH file system API, the SFTP, instead of running shell commands. For sshlib that would be [`sftp_mkdir`](https://api.libssh.org/master/group__libssh__sftp.html#ga077f9b979e13a505507f7585833245dc).*